Images attached to page builder vanish on save but the data is saved on my table (the problem is on arabic_image_one)
<?php

namespace magento\test\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;
use magento\test\Api\BannersRepositoryInterface;
use magento\test\Api\Data\BannersInterfaceFactory;
use magento\test\Model\ResourceModel\Banners\CollectionFactory as BannersItemFactory;
class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
/**
* @var RequestInterface
*/
private $request;
private $dataObjectHelper;

/**
 * @var SerializerInterface
 */
private $serializer;
/**
 * @var BannersItemFactory
 */
private BannersItemFactory $bannersItem;
/**
 * @var BannersRepositoryInterface
 */
private BannersRepositoryInterface $bannersRepository;
/**
 * @var BannersInterfaceFactory
 */
private BannersInterfaceFactory $bannersInterfaceFactory;

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param RequestInterface $request
 * @param BannersItemFactory $bannersItem
 * @param DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
 * @param BannersInterfaceFactory $bannersInterfaceFactory
 * @param BannersRepositoryInterface $bannersRepository
 * @param SerializerInterface $serializer
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    RequestInterface $request,
    BannersItemFactory $bannersItem,
    DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
    BannersInterfaceFactory $bannersInterfaceFactory,
    BannersRepositoryInterface $bannersRepository,
    SerializerInterface $serializer
) {
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->bannersItem = $bannersItem;
    $this->bannersRepository = $bannersRepository;
    $this->bannersInterfaceFactory = $bannersInterfaceFactory;
    $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
    $this->serializer = $serializer;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $data = $this->request->getPostValue();
    try {
        if (isset($data['id'])) {
            $this->update($data);
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You saved the banner.'));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index');
        } else {
            $dataArray = [
                'position' => $data['position'] ?? null,
                'name' => $data['name'] ?? null,
                'category_id' => $data['category_id'] ?? null,
                'custom_link' => $data['custom_link'] ?? null,
                'image' => isset($data['image']) ? explode('media/', $data['image'][0]['url'])[1] : null,
                'image_two' => isset($data['image_two']) ? explode('media/', $data['image_two'][0]['url'])[1] : null,
                'arabic_image_one' => isset($data['arabic_image_one']) ? explode('media/', $data['arabic_image_one'][0]['url'])[1] : null,
            ];

            $bannersSaveData = $this->bannersInterfaceFactory->create();
            $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
                $bannersSaveData,
                $dataArray,
               \magento\test\Api\Data\BannersInterface::class
            );
            $this->bannersRepository->save($bannersSaveData);
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You have saved the Brands.'));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index');
        }
    } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index');
    }
}

public function update($data)
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    try {
        $updateArray = [
            'position' => $data['position'] ?? null,
            'name' => $data['name'] ?? null,
            'category_id' => $data['category_id'] ?? null,
            'custom_link' => $data['custom_link'] ?? null,
            'image' => isset($data['image']) ? explode('media/', $data['image'][0]['url'])[1] : null,
            'image_two' => isset($data['image_two']) ? explode('media/', $data['image_two'][0]['url'])[1] : null,
            'arabic_image_one' => isset($data['arabic_image_one']) ? explode('media/', $data['arabic_image_one'][0]['url'])[1] : null,
        ];

        $bannersData = $this->bannersRepository->getById($data['id']);
        $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
            $bannersData,
            $updateArray,
            \magento\Test\Api\Data\BannersInterface::class
        );
        $this->bannersRepository->save($bannersData);
    } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/show');
    }
}

}
